# How do I insure a Macbook Pro that's over a year old?

Tags: macbook-pro, warranty, damage

I'm a huge clutz, and I constantly accidentally destroy electronics. A few days ago, I just barely caught my Macbook Pro as it almost fell off a balcony, and decided I really need insurance for this thing, specifically insurance that covers accidental damage.

The computer was bought over a year ago, so I can't get AppleCare, and from what I understand AppleCare doesn't cover accidental damage anyway. The laptop is a 2015 model 15-inch Retina Macbook Pro that costs over $2,000, and I'm terrified I won't be able to pay to repair or replace is should I break it.

How can I add insurance or a warranty of some sort so I won't have to pay for repairs, or at least have repair costs reduced to something manageable, should this happen?

Comment: I think this is pretty much off-topic here, but all my 'pricey' gear - computers, musical instruments, cameras etc are covered under the regular household insurance. Don't even have to list everything any more, like they insisted in the past.

Comment: I'm in exactly the same situation as @Tetsujin - my home insurance covers all my laptops, iPhones, iPads, cameras, etc for accidental damage. In fact, I'm even covered for damage away from the home on all _portable_ items.

Comment: @Monomeeth Unfortunately I'm renting my home

Comment: Actually, whether you're renting is irrelevant. It's the home _contents_ insurance policy that covers the items, not the _building_ insurance. If you own your home they're usually bundled together (though not necessarily), but if you're renting then you can still get coverage for your contents - otherwise how would you be covered in the event of fire, theft, etc?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Apple Software and is outside the scope of what is defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  However, in the interest of good karma, you should check out [Safeware](http://www.safeware.com/) for this type of protection.

Answer (score 1):

AppleCare isn't insurance. You should start with Amazon in your country if available and then check your local / national insurance providers to pick a policy that meets your needs.

If you already have renters or homeowners insurance, a rider might be all you need to cover computer equipment for little hassle of shopping for a policy.